# Как правильно загружать скрипты с помощью AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Я создаю сайт на php, он разделён на несколько частей, некоторые части являются общими для всех страниц, а некоторые изменяются при нажатии на внутренние ссылки левой кнопкой мыши, в этом случае вместо реальной смены страниц происходит AJAX-подгрузка нового содержимого, которым заполняются нужные элементы, примерно как

```
$('#content_area').html(loaded_content)
```

Не возникает проблем, когда загружаемый контент состоит из элементов внешнего вида, вроде div или img, но загрузка скриптов не сработает, для добавления скриптов нужна конструкция вида

```
 var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
  s.setAttribute( 'src', src );
  document.body.appendChild( s );
```

Если страница загружена первой, без помощи AJAX, скрипты будут добавлены с помощью файла типа

```
page_1_script_loader.php
```

В котором будут строчки вида

```
<script src="script_for_page_1"></script>
```

При осуществлении AJAX-подгрузки, с помощью получения содержимого файла page_1_script_loader.php, недостаточно будет просто добавить полученное содержимое на страницу, придётся выполнять код, анализируя загруженные строки, регулярными выражениями находить скрипты и их атрибуты src, а затем добавлять их с помощью описанного выше кода
Это лишняя трата времени и ресурсов

Поэтому я думаю сделать иначе - для файлов, содержащих скрипты, параллельно генерировать SQL-строку, в которой в одной из ячеек в формате JSON будут записаны расположения к подключаемым скриптам, а функцию, которая загружает содержимое с помощью AJAX, написать примерно такой

```
load_by_ajax(file_to_load, type_of_content)
{
switch (type_of_content)
{
  case 'html': just_load_html(file_to_load); break;
  case 'js': load_js(file_to_load); break;
}
}
```

И соответственно, когда функция file_to_load загрузит с сервера пути к нужным скриптам, просто вызывать callback-функцию с содержимым

```
function after_js_loaded(loaded_files){
  for (var i in loaded_files){
      var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
      s.setAttribute( 'src', loaded_files[i] );
      document.body.appendChild( s );

}
```

}

Правильно ли я делаю, или можно поступить иначе?

Comment: Не проще сразу подключить все js-скрипты?

Comment: @MAX я так и делаю, но я подумал, что есть более оптимальный вариант

Comment: Подгрузка — вряд ли оптимальный вариант. Чем меньше «дергать» сервер, тем лучше. :-)

Comment: @MAX А если в одном AJAX-запросе загружать и скрипты, и элементы внешнего вида?
То есть, количество загрузок не изменится, но изменится их величина

Comment: Обычно скрипты статичные, то есть нет смысла их подгружать дополнительно. Один раз при загрузке страницы, а дальше уже вызываем их код.